# Common variable name acronym for Pytorch or Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, pytorch

I have seen var name like ninp (num_input), nhid (num_hidden), emsize (embedding size) in pytorch example github repo. What are some of other common acronyms and their meaning/context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are common terminologies used in Sequence Models (e.g. RNNs, LSTMs, GRUs etc.,) Here is a description of what those terms mean:

`ninp (num_input)`  : Dimension of the vectors in the embedding matrix
`emsize (embedding size)`: Dimension of the vectors in the embedding matrix
 `nhid (num_hidden)`: how many "hidden" units that we want to have in each hidden layer

Pictorial description might help to understand it better. Below is a nice illustration. (Credits: Killian Levacher)

[image: RNN-terminology]

In the above figure `emsize`, is the embedding size (i.e. dimensionality of the embedding vector). This depends on the model architecture but most people would use something like `300`.

---

[image: RNN architecture]

In the above figure, we have five neurons in each "hidden" layer. Hence, the `nhid` value is 5. Output layer would have the dimensionality equal to the vocabulary size, so that a probability distribution is generated over all the tokens in the vocabulary.

Comment: That's great! what I really want is more examples of these acronyms.